# Remote State File Location

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

I have a question regarding the state file store in S3.
Let say I have my module deployed with this backup configuration

```
    bucket = "tf_state"
    key    = "dev/db"
```

I need to change the location, from `dev/db` to `npr/dev/db`.

What's the correct way to simpy relocate the state file?
Can I simply copy the file `dev/db` into `npr/dev` ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Use the aws cli to copy the state to the new bucket location (assuming you're authenticated): `aws s3 cp s3://tf_state/dev/db s3://tf_state/npr/dev/db`
2. Update your backend configuration
3. Run `terraform init`